# What's the difference between uploadify.allglyphs.swf and uploadify.swf

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I just downloaded uploadify, and there is `uploadify.allglyphs.swf`. What is it, and what's the difference between it and `uploadify.swf`. The allglyphs version is bigger than the regular one.

(Could not find any reference in the documentation or the faq, google didn't help either)

Comment: My wild guess would be that it contains a full Unicode font to label buttons with (including `ÄÖÜ` Umlauts etc.) - if Uploadify offers labeled buttons? Never seen any.

Comment: This seems to back my guess: http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/options/buttontext/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allglyphs version contains a wider character set for labeling the upload button, as discussed [here](http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussion/comment/2820/#Comment_2820).

Comment: my assumption as well, but good you found a backing explanation (sort of) :)

Answer (score 1):

THe allglyphs version probably contains a bigger character set, for allowing files with strange names (asian characters, arabic, etc.) to be uploaded.